# Load and sandbox plug-ins from memory

Tags: c#, plugins, mef, appdomain, maf

I'm developing a Windows Azure website which modifies some data based on user input and returns the data to the user. All the data modification is handled by per-user plug-ins which are stored as blobs in a [database](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/services/storage/).

Currently, when a user requests some data, I

- get all the plug-ins of that user from the database;
- [load the assemblies from memory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h538bck7.aspx);
- use reflection to find all classes which [implement a plug-in interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isassignablefrom.aspx) defined in a shared assembly;
- [instantiate them](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wccyzw83.aspx), casting them into the interface; and
- call a method from them directly, passing the data they need to modify by reference together with any appropriate user input.

This works reasonably well, and allows me to write new plug-ins for each user which operate only on their data.

However, in the longer run, I want to allow each user to write their own plug-ins based on the interface and install them simply by uploading them to the database. Thus, I need some way to restrict what the plug-ins can and can't do.

I've toyed around with a custom solution based on [AppDomains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.aspx), but I haven't yet found a way to get it working how I want it to. I've also looked at the [Managed Extensibility Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460648.aspx) and the [Managed Add-in Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384200.aspx), but none of them seem to fit the bill perfectly, with MEF not geared for the sandboxing and MAF not supporting the loading of plug-ins from memory.

- Are there any more or less ready-made solutions for my problem out there ?
- If not, how should I tackle writing my own; what's a good overall structure of dependencies between my host application, an eventual "plugin runner/sandboxer", any interfaces, contracts, adapters etc. and them the user-supplied plug-ins?
- Should I just save the plug-in assemblies locally in a temporary location to ease the job of resolving them and allow me to use any one of the frameworks available?
- Can you point me in the direction of good reading material which would make the task seem more manageable (or less, if I should just drop the whole idea of sandboxed user-supplied plug-ins already)?